# Please explain why nothing happens when I press button 2, but I get the expected result when I press button 1 in the following Java code

Tags: java

My code works only if i press the "button 1" but when i press "button 2" nothing happens.
I know something wrong with my `paint()` method and the `if...else` statement, but have no idea how to fix it.

thank you

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AnAppletWithButtons extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    Button button1, button2;
    int r, g , b;
    Color color;
    boolean drawLine = false;
    boolean fillOval = false;

    public void init()
    {
        String parmStringRED =  getParameter("red");
        r = Integer.parseInt(parmStringRED);
        String parmStringGREEN =  getParameter("green");
        g = Integer.parseInt(parmStringGREEN);
        String parmStringBLUE =  getParameter("blue");
        b = Integer.parseInt(parmStringBLUE);
        color = new Color (r,g,b);
        button1 = new Button("Button 1");
        add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(this);

        button2 = new Button("Button 2");
        add(button2);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button1.setForeground(color);
        button2.setForeground(color);

        button1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        button2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == button1) {
            System.out.println("Button 1 was pressed");
            drawLine = true;
        } else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            System.out.println("Button 2 was pressed");
            fillOval = true;
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);   // for the background
        if(drawLine){
            System.out.println(drawLine);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 400, 400);
        }
        else if(fillOval){
            System.out.println(fillOval);
            g.fillOval(10, 10, 390, 390);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It appears to be homework. Is it homework?

Comment: Did you misspell repaint()?  That would be an issue itself if so :-)

Comment: @NickCoelius I think that's how you spell `repaint()`, no? Plus it clearly works, just not as intended.

Comment: Sorry, yes.  That's how you spell repaint().  But since I was presuming that his function was paint(), I kind of assumed he was perhaps inadvertently calling a function that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break up the `else if` in `paint(Graphics g)` into two `if`s

Comment: That will suffer from the same problem, but as soon as either button is hit, it'll keep doing that operation forever.

Comment: Umm, breaking up the `else if` will make both statements be evaluated separately instead of being short circuited when `drawLine` is true. Of course once he hits both buttons, there will be no way to reset it.

Answer (score 2):

You never reset the values of `drawLine` or `fillOval`. As soon as you set `drawLine` to `true`, `paint` will always draw a line since you check for that boolean first.

If nothing else, you can reset both variables to `false` in the `paint` method, although there are other ways to resolve this.

Comment: @MikeLolo Remember to accept answers so future visitors know what the issue was!

Answer (score 0):

Change your button click event handler as follow:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == button1) {
        System.out.println("Button 1 was pressed");
        drawLine = true;
        fillOval = false;
    } else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
        System.out.println("Button 2 was pressed");
        drawLine = false;
        fillOval = true;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Regards,